# Converting strings to boolean gives only False value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to convert data (string format from a csv file) to boolean (in a dataframe), I have 'lost' information on their original value, so now all the values are boolean `False`.

The columns that I am trying to change into boolean are the following:

```
df['Col1'] =df['Col1'].astype('bool')
df['Col2'] =df['Col2'].astype('bool')
```

I have also tried with

```
df.Col1 = np.where(df.Col1.eq('true'), True, False)
df. Col2 = np.where(df.Col2.eq('true') | df.Col2.eq('tbc'), True, False)
```

The unique values for each column, Col1 and Col2 are:

```
Col1: array([true, false, nan], dtype=object)

Col2: array(['true', 'false', 'tbc', nan], dtype=object)
```

My original dataset has the following values.

```
Col1      Col2
true      true
true      true
false     false
nan       false
false     true
true      tbc
```

Though they were converted into boolean, all the values are False:

```
Col1      Col2
False     False
False     False
False     False
False     False
False     False
False     False
```

I would like to treat TBC as True. Why am I getting only False values? Any idea on how I could fix it?

Sample of original dataset and code:

```
Date                 Checked             Verified
2018-05-23           FALSE                TRUE
2018-05-24           TRUE                 TBC
2018-05-26           FALSE                TBC
2018-05-31            nan                 nan
2019-12-01           TRUE                 TRUE
2019-12-05           TRUE                 TBC
2019-12-15           TRUE                 FALSE
2019-12-23           FALSE                nan
```

Code

## Read the file csv:

```
df=pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', engine='python')
```

## Transform to lower case

```
df= df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

## Transform string to boolean

```
df['Checked'] = np.where(df['Checked'].eq('true'), True, False)
df['Verified'] = np.where(df['Verified'].eq('true') | df['Verified'].eq('tbc'), True, False)
```

Then I test how many rows have value Checked = True:

```
len(df[df['Checked']=='true'])
```

output: `153`

Convert to boolean Checked:

```
df['Checked'] = np.where(df['Checked'].eq('true'), True, False)
len(df[df['Checked']==True])
```

output: `153`

Convert `Verified` to boolean:

```
df['Verified'] = np.where(df['Verified'].eq('true') | df['Verified'].eq('tbc'), True, False)

len(df[df['Verified']==True])
```

output: `0` (expected `60`)

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right separator when reading in your data? It looks like it is space separated instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for both columns via regular expressions and `df.replace`:

```
df.astype(str).replace({'(?i)True|TBC': True, '(?i)False|nan': False}, regex=True)

    Col1   Col2
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
3  False  False
4  False   True
5   True   True
```

The pattern is case insensitive.

Comment: Thank you cs95. However I think I am doing something wrong as if I check the length `len(df[df['Col1']==True])` I get `0`, instead of `153`

Comment: @Math Your data might be different because this works for the data shown. Maybe you have leading or trailing whitespace chars in your data.

Comment: the values are only converted into lower case (I updated the question, but I think this could not cause the issue). The name of the columns are different (I have two columns called Checked and Verified, but I also think that this cannot cause the issue).Maybe because I am trying to import strings from csv?

Comment: @Math After you run the replace command. Do this : `df['Col1'].value_counts()`. This should tell you how many True and False values are there in the column.

Comment: It could have something to do with how you read the data. Could you maybe give a complete example that causes the problem? A piece of code we can execute that replicates exactly what you do?

Comment: @Cerno, I updated the question. The dataset comes from a csv file. I extracted a few rows.

Comment: @Math, I wrote an answer since the comment fields are too limited

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works perfectly. Since you haven't given the exact csv format, I assumed it would be like this:

```
Date;Checked;Verified
2018-05-23;FALSE;TRUE
2018-05-24;TRUE;TBC
2018-05-26;FALSE;TBC
2018-05-31;nan;nan
2019-12-01;TRUE;TRUE
2019-12-05;TRUE;TBC
2019-12-15;TRUE;FALSE
2019-12-23;FALSE;nan
```

Then I called the code, like you did:

```
df=pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', engine='python')
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
df['Checked'] = np.where(df['Checked'].eq('true'), True, False)
df['Verified'] = np.where(df['Verified'].eq('true') | df['Verified'].eq('tbc'), True, False)
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
         Date  Checked  Verified
0  2018-05-23    False      True
1  2018-05-24     True      True
2  2018-05-26    False      True
3  2018-05-31    False     False
4  2019-12-01     True      True
5  2019-12-05     True      True
6  2019-12-15     True     False
7  2019-12-23    False     False
```

Which python and pandas version do you use?
I tested this with Python 3.6.1 and Pandas 1.04

Comment: Yes, there was an error due to the delimiter. Thank you, Cerno